# How to remove values of a table? (MVN, Spring, Java)

Tags: java, spring

Today I have to find a way, how to manage a Stock.
Later you should be able to add items(What already works) and remove items(What doesnt work until now).
But now I am having Problems to find a method, which searches within the table and which looks for matchings and removing them.
Therefor I use the variables (Productamount(Integer), Productname(String)), those are being searched by an if-operation, to check if they are aviable or not.
(And I am asking myself if there is an option to remove tablerows directly by clicking? E.g. by clicking on a cross the whole table is removed. Because this would be an idea, too.)
Thats my table with it's textinputs:

```
<table id="invoverview" border="1">
            <caption>Bestand</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Produktbezeichnung</th>
                    <th>Anzahl</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="entry : ${products.entries}">
                    <td th:text="${entry.getProductname()}">H</td>
                    <td th:text="${entry.getProductamount()}">A</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div>
            <form name="entry" action="entry" method="POST">
                <h3>Neuer Lagereintrag(Stockentry):</h3>
                <label>Produktbezeichnung(ItemDescription) 
  <input  id="ProductName" name="ProductName" /></label><br/>
                 <label>Produktanzahl(ProductAmount) 
  <input id="ProductAmount" name="ProductAmount" /></label><br/>
            <button type="submit"  href="/entry">Einfügen(Insert)</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form name="delentry" action="delentry" method="POST">
                <h3>Lagereintrag Löschen:</h3>
                <label>Produktbezeichnung <input id="ProductName" name="ProductName" /></label><br />
                <label>Produktmenge <input id="ProductAmount" name="ProductAmount"  /></label><br />
            <button type="submit" href="/delentry">Entfernen(Remove)</button>
            </form>
```

StockEntry.java:

```
public class StockEntry {

public String getProductname() {
   return productname;
    }

    public void setProductname(String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
    } 

      public Integer getProductamount() {
      return productamount;
      }

      public void setProductamount(Integer productamount) {
      this.productamount = productamount;
      }

     public StockEntry(String productname, Integer productamount) {
     this.productname = productname;
     this.productamount = productamount;
     }

    private String productname;
    private Integer productamount;

   }
```

And an exerpt of StockController.java: (entry should create a Stockentry and delentry should delete/remove an entry)

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/entry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setNewEntry(Model model,  @RequestParam("ProductName") 
String productname,

     @RequestParam("ProductAmount") Integer productamount) {
products.newEntry(productname,productamount);
models(model);

    return "stock";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/delentry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String delEntry(Model model,  @RequestParam("ProductName")  
String   productname,
                      @RequestParam("ProductAmount") Integer productamount) {
products.delEntry(productname,productamount);
System.out.println(productamount);
System.out.println(productname);
models(model);

return "stock";
}
```

And thats an exerpt from stock.java( in delEntry I want to check, if LinkedList entries contains the both vars productname and productname):

```
private LinkedList<StockEntry> entries;

public Stock(){
this.productname = null;
this.productamount = 0;
this.entries = new LinkedList<>();
}

public Iterable<StockEntry> getEntries(){
return this.entries;
}
public void newEntry(String productname, Integer productamount){
 StockEntry entry = new StockEntry(productname, productamount);
 this.entries.add(entry);
 for (StockEntry bla : this.entries){
    System.out.println(bla.getProductname());
    System.out.println(bla.getProductamount());
} }
public void delEntry(String productname, Integer productamount){
 StockEntry entry = new StockEntry(productname, productamount);
 if(this.entries.contains(productname)&& this.entries.equals(productamount)){
    this.entries.remove();
  }
 }
}
}
```

I have to say that adding entries works already.(But how is it possible to make to make the Inputsflieds required? "required" as Html-tag doesn't work. I think somewhere I have to place @NotNull or @NotEmpty)
But is the if-Operation correct? Before I already tried "Stock.getProductname().contains(productname)" and "Stock.getProductamount().equals(productamount)", but it didnt work because getProductamount() & getProductname() arent static, if they are static only nonsense will be in the table ( 5 times the same entry..)
In the ApplicationInitializer.java this Products will be created:

```
private void initializeStock(){
products.newEntry("Kastenbier", 50);
products.newEntry("Kastenwasser", 5);
products.newEntry("Kastencola", 500);
products.newEntry("Schnaps", 50000);
products.newEntry("Döner", 9); }
```

They will be loaded in the table Stock.html. Works already.
Only removing doesn't work now. 
Friends were talking of a enum, that the stock could be made with an enum. But enums are fix and not thought to be dynamic(editable).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public void delEntry(String productname, Integer productamount){
     Optional<StockEntry> entryToDelete = this.entries.filter(e ->productName.equals(e.getProductName()) && productamount == e.getProductAmount()).findFirst();
     if(entryToDelete.isPresent()) {
          this.entries.remove(entryToDelete.get());
     }
```

}

This will first find the entry identified by its productname and amount. If a product was find, it will be removed from the list.

The problem with your code is, that you try to find a StockEntry only by its name but you always remove the first item.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot shorter than the old pre-lambada way, lmao

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I will try it right now.

Comment: Well IntellJ has some problems with filter.... 
Screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTKefGz6s53UDRCVGV0YlJ0THc/view?usp=sharing

"Can't resolve method ' filter < lamba Expression>' " and somehow getProductname() & getProductamount() aren't accessible. 

Something must be wrong in my Code...

Comment: Is your intellij language level for that project set to be for java 8? Do you have jdk 8 installed?

Comment: Yes Java SDK 1.8.

Comment: Please note there was a little typo. It's `isPresent` (instead of `isPreset`). I fixed it. This should work with Java 8, do you still get this error? Maybe cleaning the project will help.

Comment: Yes, the error remains. 
Now I use hashmap not linkedlist, because Lists you are always able to Change the end and start, not the values within.

Comment: You can change the values in a `List`, you don't need a `HashMap` for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your delEntry method, specifically, this line:

`if(this.entries.contains(productname)&& this.entries.get()(productamount)){`

Think about what that line is trying to do, first it checks if the entry name, which is a string, is in the list of entries, which is never going to be true, because your items are StockEntry objects, **not strings**, then you try and check if the **list of entries** IS the price, which should never be true.

Maybe try changing it to this, and see if it works.

```
public void delEntry(String productname, Integer productamount){
 StockEntry entry = new StockEntry(productname, productamount);
 StockEntry to_remove;
 for(StockEntry item : this.entries){
   if(item.getProductName().equals(productname) && item.getProductamount() ==   productamount){
         to_remove = item;
         break; //or return, i forget how to java.
   }
 }
 //I remove it outside the loop to prevent a ConcurrentModificationException
 if(to_remove != null){ 
   this.entries.remove(to_remove);
   //done!
 }
}
```

Edit: If you can use java 8 methods and stuff, i would recommend [@Ria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550169/1932789), because it's short and does the same thing as mine

Comment: This works for the Products which are initialized in initializeStock()...
But for manual entries it doesnt work. Strange Thing.  Have to check /entry.